# Open browser in angular2 and jump into a route path (page), broken due router alpha 0.7

Tags: angular

so with the latest angular 2 we had to remove all prefixed forward slashes in routes and I am not sure if this is because of it or a new feature, but now with ng2 0.7 the index.html is removed from the URL path...

so before a route would look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/src/public/index.html/App1/Dashboard
```

but now routes look like

```
http://localhost:8080/src/public/App1/Dashboard
```

and so the problem is that if I want to reload a server (any server) and go directly to this page /App1/Dashboard my server gives a 404 error

so the question is, how do we configure now a local node server, or maybe the solution as at the router level, so we can jump directly into a page... as again, because the router now removes the index.html prefix in the url it just ends up being 404 error

regards

Sean

Comment: This means you had something wrong with the old router version. The new URL is the correct one and you should have got that with the old router already. We would need to see some code (bootstrap, routes, ...) to investigate.

Comment: Have an example of a node server you use you can reload

Answer (score 0):

Example of node server?

```
    import * as express from 'express';
    import {ng2engine} from 'angular2-universal-preview';

    // Angular 2
    import {App} from './src/app';

    let app = express();

    // Express View
    app.engine('.ng2.html', ng2engine);
    app.set('views', __dirname);
    app.set('view engine', 'ng2.html');


    // static files
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));


    app.use('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index', { App });
    });



    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('Listen on http://localhost:3000');
    });
```

Comment: tx but I don't want to use server side rendering, just a simple server that I can reload even when the routes changes (i.e: index.html is removed from the URL)